# Django, how to trigger functions at a specific time?

Tags: django

I have a Django Model which has a published_at field. I want to execute a function every 24 hrs after the published_at everyday. So if,

```
publish_at = '5 Feb 2020 12AM'

At 6 Feb 2020 12AM , a set of methods will be implemented
At 7 Feb 2020 12AM , a set of methods will be implemented

for x days
```

Comment: Search “django cron” - should find a bunch of utility libraries and approaches that can integrate - https://www.google.com/search?q=djnago+cron

Comment: look into django cron or django-celery